# How to repeat eficiently part of plot for succesive plots in PyPlot or Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am making a succesion of plots for an animation that consists of a colormap that changes and has a diagram of a neuron over it that is static.
The heatmap is very easy to plot for the computer, and is fast, but the diagram of the neuron is quite laborious ( some 4000 data points ) and takes a lot of to repeat it for every frame. So I thought, can it be possible to only redraw the heatmap?

I am using PyPlot through Julia, so my code looks like this:

```
for t=1:801
    f=figure(figsize=(4,3))
    imshow(lfp3[t,:,:], extent=[-700,700,-400,1200], origin="lower")
    for l in cel2
        plot(l[:,1], l[:,2], marker="None", linewidth=1)
    end
    nstring=lpad(t, 4, "0")
    nom="tubuela-$nstring"*".png"
    savefig(nom,dpi=72)
    close()
    if mod(t,50)==0
        println("listos $t")
    end
end
```

Comment: is the neuron diagram that takes long to plot on top or on bottom? In the latter case you can prepare the backgorund image, `deepcopy`  it and reuse as many times as you need.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Code's not reproducible so I can't be sure, but I think the `imshow` does the changing heatmap (it's dependent on iteration variable `t`) and the `cel2` part plots the neuron from a series of lines.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, no internet in my home for some days. Yes, the imshow does the changing heatmap and the plot part does the Neuron Drawing as a series of lines.

Comment: Okey, how I deepcopy a plot?